# Literally 'writing' on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Has anyone got any ideas on how I could make literal writing on a page, like on PowerPoint the user can write over the presentation?
I understand that placing a div 1px square could do the job, but thought that this could lead to messy code (as well as a lot of it!)

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

EDIT: I can't use canvas as the rest of the project won't support it, unless somehow canvas can be made transparent and put with a higher zIndex than the rest of the document.

Comment: What do you mean by 'literal writing'?

Comment: I believe that literal writing would involve a sharpie and a monitor.

Comment: The Canvas element is well suited for this, but I takes some code to accomplish this.  SVG could be another option.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you are asking how to do virtual writing on top of a web page, look into Canvas.

Comment: Where the user can click and drag and it draws a line, curve etc. where they dragged the mouse across

Comment: SVG would be a better solution if you want the HTML behind it to be also interactable.

Comment: re: Edit, canvas backgrounds, AFAIK, are transparent by default.

Comment: @StorySystems - The background of `canvas` is always transparent by default.

Comment: Are you using HTML5? What about the `contenteditable` attribute? http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/DqZX8/

```
function drawingArea(ele) {
    var width = ele.scrollWidth,
        height = ele.scrollHeight,
        area = $("<svg>").attr({
            width: width,
            height: height,
            class: "draw"
        }).appendTo(ele),
        tracking = false;

    var mDown = false,
        id, line;

    $(window).mousedown(function (e) {
        if (tracking) {
            mDown = true;
            id = Date.now();
            line = $("<path>").appendTo(area).attr({
                d: [
                    "M",
                    e.clientX + ele.scrollLeft,
                    e.clientY + ele.scrollTop
                ].join(" "),
                id: id
            });
        }
    }).mousemove(function (e) {
        if (mDown) {
            line.attr({
                d: line.attr("d") + " " + [
                    "L",
                    e.clientX + ele.scrollLeft,
                    e.clientY + ele.scrollTop
                ].join(" ")
            });
            area[0].outerHTML = area[0].outerHTML;
            area = $("svg");
            line = area.find("#" + id);
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }).mouseup(function () {
        mDown = false;
    });

    return {
        area: area,
        startTrack: function () {
            tracking = true;
        },
        stopTrack: function () {
            tracking = false;
        },
        get isTracking() {
            return tracking;
        }
    };
}

var pad = new drawingArea(document.body);
pad.startTrack();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at canvas or svg. That will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write on a web page it's possible to use the property `contenteditable="true"`

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)